# Creating Web-service for modifying XPO objects by timer

Tags: timer, devexpress, xpo

I have several clients that create new objects. When new object is created I need to start a timer that will change some object properties when time is elapsed (each object can be visible only for defined client groups certain time).
I want to use for this purpuses web-service and wrote a method that starts timer.

For example I need to set timer to 5 minutes. Are there any restrictions for executing time? Will a timer keep my web-service alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, I don't understand your task completely, but your idea about Web Service usage looks strange to me.  Web Services are usually used to process requests from remote clients.  I.e. a client calls method of a Web Service and Web Service returns a result to this client.

I think, I got your idea :). If you need to just change data in the DB, I think the better solution is to create a windows service which will ping web service when needed.

Comment: yes, and you are right, but unfortunately I don't have the ability to use win service :)